# Understanding recursion function while checking if a binary tree is a subtree of another one

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to understand if a tree t is a subtree of tree s. I have the following code and it does not work.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
    private boolean result = false;
    public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode s, TreeNode t) {
        return isTinS(s, t);
    }
    
    public boolean isTinS(TreeNode s, TreeNode t) {
        if (t==null) return true;
        if (s==null) return false;

        if (s.val == t.val) {
           return isSame(s,t);
        }
        return isTinS(s.left, t) || isTinS(s.right, t);
    }
    
    public boolean isSame(TreeNode s, TreeNode t) {
        if (s==null && t==null) return true;
        if (s==null || t==null) return false;
        return s.val==t.val && isSame(s.left, t.left) && isSame(s.right, t.right);
    }
}
```

If I change the if condition in isTinS function, it works. I am having a hard time figuring out the difference between the two codes.

```
    public boolean isTinS(TreeNode s, TreeNode t) {
        if (t==null) return true;
        if (s==null) return false;
     
        if (isSame(s,t)) {
            return true;
        }
        return isTinS(s.left, t) || isTinS(s.right, t);
    }
```

Could someone explain how are they different or point me to some good resources for understanding such concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the value at the root of `t` appeared *twice* in `s`, but only one of those was at the root of a subtree matching `t`.  If your first code hit the wrong one first, it would return `false` and never go on to look for the other, while the second would continue the search.